# Подсветка курсора

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть подсветка курсора, выполненная следующим образом:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  let cp,
    elems = [],
    whp,
    dsp,
    pos,
    getProps = th => {  
      pos = th.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        w: pos.width,
        h: pos.height,
        p: {
          top: pos.top,
          left: pos.left
        },
        e: th
      };
    },
    all = (...args) => {
      let tmp;
      if (args.length > 2)
        for (let i = 0, len = args[0].length; i < len; i++) {
          tmp = args[1](args[0][i], i);
          if (tmp === args[2])
            break;
          if (tmp === args[3])
            continue;
        }
      else
        for (let i = 0, len = args[0].length; i < len; i++)
          args[1](args[0][i], i);

    },
    tpto = (e, filter, tmp /*tmp переменная пуста, просто объявил так*/) => {
      cp = {
          t: event.clientY,
          l: event.clientX
        },
        all(elems, (th, i) => { /*итерируем массив с элментами*/
          if (filter && (tmp = th[0]))/*проверка на родителя, в случае, если он указан в filter, это можно убрать для оптимизации в большенстве случаев, однако это же понадобится в паре с прокруткой, для обновления подсветки только в прокручиваемом блоке*/
            while (!0) {
              if (tmp === filter)
                break;
              tmp = tmp.parentNode;/*если такого родителя нет, делаем continue*/
              if (!tmp)
                return ">";
            }
          whp = getProps(th[0]),
            whp.b = getProps(th[1]),
            dsp = {
              l: whp.e.getAttribute("b-left-despos"),
              t: whp.e.getAttribute("b-top-despos")
            },/*атрибуты для поправок в положении подсветки, всяких фокусов с изменением размеров и т.д.*/
            dsp.t ? (
              dsp.t = Function("it,cursor,temp", "return " + dsp.t)(whp, cp)) : (
              dsp.t = cp.t - whp.b.h / 2 - whp.p.top),
            dsp.l ? (
              dsp.l = Function("it,cursor,temp", "return " + dsp.l)(whp, cp)) : (
              dsp.l = cp.l - whp.b.w / 2 - whp.p.left),
            whp.b.e.style.left = dsp.l + "px",/*ставим подсветке полученные координаты*/
            whp.b.e.style.top = dsp.t + "px";
        }, "!", ">");
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", tpto);
  const Main = th => {
    let back = document.createElement("div");
    back.setAttribute("b", ""),
      back.style.top = "200%",/*чтоб подсветка не выползала после загрузки страницы*/
      back.style.left = "200%",
      th.appendChild(back),
      elems.push([th, back]);
  };
  class el extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let th = this;
      Main(th),
        th.activate = () => Main(th);
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
      let elem,
        th = this;
      all(elems, (el, i) => {
        if (el[0] === th) {
          elem = i;
          return "t";
        }
      }, "t");
      elems.splice(elem, 1);
    }
  }
  customElements.define("f-dplane", el);
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

f-dplane:not([sensor]) {
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

f-dplane:not([sensor]) div {
  position: absolute;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13), transparent, transparent) no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}
[r]{
width:200px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:3px;
border:1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.14);
}
```

```html
<div r><f-dplane></f-dplane></div>
<div r><f-dplane></f-dplane></div>
<div r><f-dplane></f-dplane></div>
<div r><f-dplane></f-dplane></div>
<div r><f-dplane></f-dplane></div>
```

Проблема в том, что все блоки подсветки постоянно двигаются за курсором.. И я не знаю, как более оптимально решить эту проблему. Сначала хотел шаманить с расчётом расстояния от курсора до блока и от блока до блока, но подумал, что это очень нехорошо кончится

Answer (score 1):

Просто оставлю это здесь

```js
container.addEventListener('mousemove',e=>{
  darkness.style.top = e.pageY - darkness.offsetHeight/2 + "px";
  darkness.style.left = e.pageX -darkness.offsetWidth/4 - document.body.offsetWidth/2 + "px";
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 background:url(https://www.kino-teatr.ru/art/2104/17910.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.darkness {
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: -50%;
 background: radial-gradient(transparent,rgba(0,0,0,0.7),black,black, black,black, black,black,black,black);
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="container">
  <div class="darkness" id="darkness"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Йо-хо-хо, поганые трюмные крысы!

Comment: где моя бутылка рома! )))

Comment: это, безусловно, идея хорошая.. Однако она не учитывает того, что курсор может быть за дивом, а если это учитывать, то получится почти то же, что и у меня. Хотя вот масштабировать сам блок, а не background я не додумался тогда, когда пытался так же, была куча проблем, но теперь конечно лучше выйдет, спасибо(да, в ответе такого нет, но идея появилась благодаря нему). И всё же главная задача не решена.